# fast version of ismember() function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, performance

My question is about finding an alternative approach to what `ismember()` does in MATLAB in a much more faster way.

Here is my problem:

```
M [92786253*1]  (a: roughly 100M rows)
x [749*1]       (b: # of rows can vary from 100 to 10K)
```

I want to find rows in `b` that co-exists in `a` (the row indices of a). **This operation needs to be repeated about 10M times** for different version of `b`.

**The Normal Approach:**

```
 tic
 ind1 = ismember(M,x);
 toc

 Elapsed time is 0.515627 seconds.
```

**The Fast Approach:**

```
 tic
 n = 1;
 ind2 = find(any(all(bsxfun(@eq,reshape(x.',1,n,[]),M),2),3));
 toc

 Error using bsxfun
 Requested 92786253x1x749 (64.7GB) array exceeds maximum array size preference. 
 Creation of arrays greater than this limit may take a long time and cause MATLAB to become unresponsive.
 See array size limit or preference panel for more information.

 Error in demo_ismember_fast (line 23)
 ind2 = find(any(all(bsxfun(@eq,reshape(x.',1,n,[]),M),2),3))
```

The second approach is usually 15-20 times faster than the normal one, however in this case, I cannot use it for memory limitation. Are there any suggestion how to speedup this operation? Thanks for sharing expert opinions with me!

Comment: I guess buy 64Gb of RAM? :P This is a very big problem, you need to expect it to be slow

Comment: If so, why in the first case, I do not receive any error? I also think there can be other tricks for this except using `ismember() `.

Comment: Any constraints there? Is either of `M` or `x` sorted?

Comment: Yes, they are both sorted.

Answer (score 2):

You might find the internal (built-in) `ismembc` function useful - it can be an order of magnitude faster than `ismember`: http://UndocumentedMatlab.com/blog/ismembc-undocumented-helper-function

Note that `ismembc` only works correctly for sorted non-sparse non-Nan numeric data.

Answer (score 1):

If you can work with sorted `a` here are two alternative methods. Before starting 100M iterations some required input variables and the output variable `ind` are initialized and at each iteration `ind` is modified and at the end all element of it is set to `false`;

**interp1:**

```
s=sort(M);
edge = [-Inf s(2:end) Inf];
v = [1:numel(M) numel(M)];
ind = false(size(M));
%for ... 100M iterations
    tic
    bin = interp1(edge,v,x,'previous');
    ind(bin)= ind(bin)==x;
    toc
    %...
    ind(bin) = false;%at the end of each loop set all elements of ind to 0;
%end
```

**histcounts:**

```
s=sort(M);
edge= [-Inf s(2:end) Inf];
ind = false(size(M));
%for ... 100M iterations
    tic
    [~,~,bin]=histcounts(x,edge);
    ind(bin)= ind(bin)==x;
    toc
    %...
    ind(bin) = false;
%end
```

Comment: Thanks for these suggestions, in my original question, we have `M` and `x`, can you modify the answer based on this? also have your incorporated for, because of the 100M iterations i mentioned or it is needed for 1 iteration please?

Comment: It is assumed that for loop  has 100M iterations. I will change the variables.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, can you also mention what `out` stands for?

Comment: Answer updated,correcting errors and some explanation added .